# keras model.evaluate() does not show loss

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, reinforcement-learning

I've created a neural network of the following form in `keras`:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Input
from keras import Model

input_dim_v = 3
hidden_dims=[100, 100, 100]

inputs = Input(shape=(input_dim_v,))
net = inputs

for h_dim in hidden_dims:
    net = Dense(h_dim)(net)
    net = Activation("elu")(net)

outputs = Dense(self.output_dim_v)(net)
model_v = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model_v.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])
```

Later, I train it on single examples using `model_v.train_on_batch(X[i],y[i])`.

To test, whether the neural network is becoming a better function approximator, I wanted to evaluate the model on the accumulated `X` and `y` (in my case, `X` and `y` grow over time) periodically. However, when I call `model_v.evaluate(X, y)`, only the characteristic progress bars appear in the console, but neither the loss value nor the mse-metric (which are the same in this case) are printed.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loss and metric values are not shown in the progress bar of `evaluate()` method. Instead, they are returned as the output of the `evaluate()` method and therefore you can print them:

```
for i in n_iter:
    # ... get the i-th batch or sample

    # ... train the model using the `train_on_batch` method

    # evaluate the model on whole or part of test data
    loss_metric = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
    print(loss_metric)
```

[According to the documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate), if your model has multiple outputs and/or metrics, you can use `model.metric_names` attribute to find out what the values in `loss_metric` correspond to.