# Accuracy and Precision in Keras models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, precision-recall

I'm trying to manually calculate accuracy and precision of my Keras model. I looked at the metrics.py function and it has the below code to calculate precision.

```
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
   '''Calculates the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
   how many selected items are relevant.
   '''
   true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
   predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
   precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
return precision
```

What I don't understand is why should we do the y_true * y_pred to get the true positives? My y_pred is a vector of length 7, which has the probability for each pixel in my image and my y_true is a one-hot encoded vector of legnth 7. 
Can anyone please help me understand the y_true * y_pred in calculating true positives.

Also using the above precision function as reference, I'm using the below custom function for accuracy.

```
def overall_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_2D = K.max(y_true, axis=1, keepdims=False)
    y_pred_2D = K.max(y_true*y_pred, axis=1, keepdims=False)
    y_true_f = K.sum(K.flatten(y_true_2D))
    y_pred_f = K.sum(K.flatten(y_pred_2D))
    acc = y_pred_f / (y_true_f)

return acc
```

Is it correct way to calculate accuracy ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing multi-label classification or single-label classification?

Comment: @today Iam doing semantic segmentation of my image. trying to find probability that each pixel belong to one of the 7 class. Would you call it multi-label classification?

Comment: In your specification of the problem, can a single pixel belong to more than one class? Then it is multi-label classification, otherwise it is single label classification; and this `precision` function you referred to, is used for multi-label case (as it has been mentioned in its docstring).

Comment: @today No a single pixel can belong to only one class. How do I calculate precision  and accuracy for single-label classification problem ?

Comment: Then you can use the `metrics=['accuracy']` argument when compiling the model. Then if you would like to evaluate your model on new test data, you can use [`evaluate`](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate) method. Since you have used `'accuracy'` as a metric, one of the outputs of `evaluate` method would be the accuracy of the model. Read the docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238710/2099607) for more info.

Comment: @today yes, I did use metrics=['accuracy'] and loss = 'binary_crossentrophy' . But I wanted to confirm that the accuracy I get using evaluate method is correct by manually calculating the accuracy. And i wasnt sure how to manually calculate accuracy. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180299/discussion-between-lisa-mathew-and-today).

Comment: `binary_crossentropy` as the loss? You are not doing multi-label classification so why `binary_crossentropy`? And possibly, you have used `sigmoid` as the activation of last layer?